# what NEC addresses using GFI breakers to address outlets with no ground

Tags: electrical-panel

What NEC section addresses the use of GFI breakers to remedy ungrounded outlets

Answer (score 1):

NEC 210.8 covers GFCI , in my 2014 version the replacement of 2 prong receptacles with 3 prong when GFCI protected was in 406.4.d 
But not the same in 2017 , I will update this when I find it for the 17 code.
I looked at 406.4.d and did not see it in 17 code 
250.130.c  “non grounding receptacle replacement” information note states see.406.4.d ,,, oops I must have been in 404.6 because this time 406.4 paragraph D replacements subsection c specify replacing 2 prong with 3 prong. Sorry about that 
406.4.D.2.c is the paragraph you ask for.

Comment: Oops, I think this is what the OP wanted...